# Django console email backend in production with gunicorn and nginx

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I used django console email backend in development and It worked fine. Now for test I tried production with gunicorn and nginx, but I have no email backend for now so I used django console email backend again for sending emails, where can I see emails? is there any log to check them? or In production console backend wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The logs will be visible in the gunicorn logs, you need to configure the logfile in gunicon configuration.

Comment: I tried access log, error log and debug log level, but there is no email log in them! Can you say what I need to add for logging django email console?